# LISP Program for making a SImple Summation formula Σi. My code is Returning NIL and then the value I want, Can i not get NIL somehow?

Tags: lisp

[Question Asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUzxa.png)

```
    (defun a-sum(n p)

       (setq sum 0)
             
       ( loop for i from n to p  

           do(setq sum (+ sum i))
    )

    (format t "~d" sum)       
)
```

My code works for all of my Test Cases but using the loop method I keep returning a NIL right before my value. Is there any way to stop this? Or maybe an alernative method I'm meant to use when faced with a probem like this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73847176/124319

Comment: Do not use `setq` on a variable you have not defined!!!  The effect of this is not well defined by ANSI Common Lisp, but in most implementations it binds a value to the global variable. Use `let` to bind local variables; `(let ((sum 0)) ... (loop ...))`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the book or tutorial which recommended you to use `setq` on variable names not seen before, right in the middle of a function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code formatted in a readable way, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting when asking question and follow the conventional ways of formatting the programming language your question is about:

```
(defun a-sum (n p)
  (setq sum 0)
  (loop for i from n to p  
    do (setq sum (+ sum i)))
  (format t "~d" sum))
```

There are some problems here, notably:

- you call `SETQ` on symbol `sum`, but there is no variable in scope that is declared with such a name. You introduce variables with `let`, for example:

  ```
    (let ((sum 0))
      ;; here you are allowed to use SETQ
      (setq sum 1))
  ```

  Strictly speaking, your code is not a conforming program for Lisp, but it still works: the call to `SETQ` does modify the `symbol-value` of `sum`, so that's as-if you used a global variable. This is usually not a good idea since then your functions have effects that are not localized to their body, but also change the environment.
- In a function body, the **last** expression is the value returned by the function, so here the value being returned is the result of evaluating `(format ...)`. In the case you format to a stream, which is the case here, the return value is always NIL. That's why you have a NIL result. If you want to return `sum` then you need to have `sum` as the last expression in your function.
- Generally speaking, a function should do one thing, not mix different actions together: either you compute a sum, or you print it, but try not doing both at the same time (except when debugging).
- The `loop` construct is powerful enough to do the job with needing to use an intermediate `sum`, calling `do (setq ...)`, etc. Read [LOOP for black belts](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) and you should be able to rewrite it more concisely.
- The sum of consecutive numbers is a well-known formula that admits a solution without loops.

Answer (score 1):

I have been resisting giving an answer, because instructors should not ask students questions like this (see below).

The question is to write a function which computes the sum of i from n to p, where n and p are integers, n and p >= 0 and p >= n (the question does not state this latter requirement, and it's easy to relax it in the answer, but let's assume it).

Well, before you write some laborious and futile loop, think a bit.  Write out the sum by hand:

```
s = n + n+1 + ... + p
  =   (n + n+1 + ... + p
     + p + p-1 + ... + n)/2
  = (n+p + n+p + ... + n+p)/2
```

And now there are (p - n + 1) terms in this sum, all of which are n+p.  So

```
s = (p - n + 1)*(n+p)/2
```

Or

```
(defun a-sum (n p)
  (/ (* (+ (- p n) 1)
        (+ n p))
     2))
```

And here's why you do this:

```
> (time (a-sum/mindless 0 1000000000))

Evaluation took:
  6.716 seconds of real time
  6.716005 seconds of total run time (6.713082 user, 0.002923 system)
  100.00% CPU
  0 bytes consed
  
500000000500000000
> (time (a-sum 0 1000000000))
Evaluation took:
  0.000 seconds of real time
  0.000003 seconds of total run time (0.000002 user, 0.000001 system)
  100.00% CPU
  0 bytes consed
  
500000000500000000
```

So here's the thing: if you are the instructor and you're reading this (which I am sure you are, because I would be) *don't ask questions which have well-known closed-form solutions and expect students to write the terrible brute-force solution*, because doing that is *teaching people to be bad programmers*, and you should not do that.